# How to use a component created in another project

Tags: gtk, glade

In a project (.glade file) I created a `GtkChooserDialog` and modified to my liking.
Now I want to use this `GtkChooserDialog` in another glade project, for example to use it as a `dialogue` to `GtkChooserButton`.
But I want to make it through the glade, ie without using code (C, Python, ...)

Is this possible?

Comment: Which chooser? `GtkChooser` isn't a thing; it's just a naming convention, and specific classes may or may not provide the functionality you want.

Comment: Ok, I think the example brought confusion. So forget this example and imagine that in a file called `button.glade` you have a `button` and another file called `box.glade` you have a `Gtk.Box`.
Now you want add the `button` of the `button.glade` file in the `Gtk.Box` of the `box.glade` file.

How to do this only through glade, ie without using code (C, Python, ...)?

The XML glade file can import elements that are in another XML file?

Comment: Look up composite widget templates.